# Talend Open Studio - java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 - tMap

Tags: java, html, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception, talend

I made a tHttpRequest from a website page and got the html code but i need to extract a part of it and can't manage to do it because everytime i try StringHandling.RIGHT(row9.newColumn,StringHandling.INDEX(row9.newColumn,"\<p class="ecl-paragraph"\>")) it gives me the error:

Exception in component tMap_3 (try2)
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

I've tried many ways, through tExtractXMLField, tMap, writing into all the other types of files and read again to see if i can go by index.

This is a part of the html code i have:
"

```
              <meta charset="utf-8" />
              <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
              <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
             <meta name="robots" content="follow, index" />
             <meta name="googlebot" content="follow, index" />
             <meta name="revisit-after" content="15 days" />
             <meta name="description" content="Fisheries - Commercial designations" />
             <meta name="creator" content="COMM/MARE/A.4" />
             <meta name="reference" content="Fisheries" />
             <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />
             <meta name="classification" content="22000" />
             <meta name="keywords" content="Fisheries,Commercial designations" />"
```

...

```
 "<dd id="ecl-accordion-panel-comb-nomenc" class="ecl-accordion__panel " role="region" aria-labelledby="ecl-accordion-header-comb-nomenc" aria-hidden="true">
        
             <p class="ecl-paragraph">
                 An annually revised goods classification scheme used in EU for the purposes of customs duty and foreign trade statistics. The scheme is based on the Harmonized System nomenclature, further extended with Community subdivisions. Each subdivision is identified by an eight-digit numerical code.
                 <a 
  href="https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/business/calculation-customs-duties/what-is-common-customs-tariff/combined-nomenclature_en" title="Combined Nomenclature" target="_blank" class="ecl-link ecl-u-d-block ecl-u-mt-xxxs">Read more: Combined Nomenclature</a>
        </p>
        
            <div class="ecl-u-pa-s ecl-u-bg-default mare-u-border-grey-10"><ul class="ecl-list ecl-listing ecl-list--unstyled mare-u-max-width-none mare-tree mare-tree-s"><li><a aria-controls="expandable-626" aria-expanded="true" class="ecl-link ecl-expandable__button expand mare-tree-item" href="#" id="expandable-button-626"><span><span class = "mare-u-fw-bold" >16</span> &mdash; CHAPTER 16 - PREPARATIONS OF MEAT, OF FISH OR OF CRUSTACEANS, MOLLUSCS OR OTHER AQUATIC INVERTEBRATES</span></a><ul aria-hidden="false" class="ecl-list--unstyled ecl-u-aria" aria-labelledby="expandable-button-626" id="expandable-626"><li><a aria-controls="expandable-630" aria-expanded="true" class="ecl-link ecl-expandable__button expand mare-tree-item" href="#" id="expandable-button-630"><span><span class = "mare-u-fw-bold" >1604</span> &mdash; Prepared or preserved fish; caviar and caviar substitutes prepared from fish eggs</span></a><ul aria-hidden="false" class="ecl-list--unstyled ecl-u-aria" aria-labelledby="expandable-button-630" id="expandable-630"><li><a aria-controls="expandable-631" aria-expanded="true" class="ecl-link ecl-expandable__button expand mare-tree-item" href="#" id="expandable-button-631"><span>Fish, whole or in pieces, but not minced</span></a><ul aria-hidden="false" class="ecl-list--unstyled ecl-u-aria" aria-labelledby="expandable-button-631" id="expandable-631"><li><a aria-controls="expandable-643" aria-expanded="true" class="ecl-link ecl-expandable__button expand mare-tree-item" href="#" id="expandable-button-643"><span><span class = "mare-u-fw-bold" >1604 14</span> &mdash; Tuna, skipjack and bonito (Sarda spp.)</span></a><ul aria-hidden="false" class="ecl-list--unstyled ecl-u-aria" aria-labelledby="expandable-button-643" id="expandable-643"><li class="mare-tree-leaf"><span class="mare-tree-item"><span class = "mare-u-fw-bold ecl-tag__item ecl-u-ma-none ecl-u-bg-primary ecl-u-color-white ecl-u-d-inline-block" >1604 14 90</span> &mdash; Bonito (Sarda spp.)</span></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>
             </div>
     </dd>
     </dl>
                 </div>
             </div>
            
            </main>
             <div class="mare-banner-feedback ecl-u-pv-xl">"
```

...

The part i need to extract is:

An annually revised goods classification scheme used in EU for the purposes of customs duty and foreign trade statistics. The scheme is based on the Harmonized System nomenclature, further extended with Community subdivisions. Each subdivision is identified by an eight-digit numerical code.
                Read more: Combined Nomenclature

I am new to Talend and have been trying to solve this for many days but can not find a way. Would really appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure i am using the componet tExtractXMLField correctly as i do not know much about the subject.

Comment: Not sure why are you using tMap. If you are making single call to web service and getting result in a context variable, then you can use tJava component to do the String operation within that.

Comment: @CleanBold Thank you, yes, that is how i resolved the problem.